# rasdial fails and status is connecting for long time

Tags: windows, networking

While the rasdial connection fails with ERROR CODE678 or 777, the rasdial connection status (control panel-->network and internet -->Network connections -->) hungs in connecting/disconnecting state for long time... which leads to consequent connect/disconnect fail as well.

During this connecting/disconnecting state, we couldn't do any operations like delete/stop....the only solution is to reboot the pc. Also, in the properties of the rasdial connection, we have changed the redial number to 0. Even after changing this, at time, this happens.. Is there a any way to debug or solve this issue?

We are using windows 7.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found this at FinalBuilder.com

"Note that rasdial.exe counts the number of times a connection is established and will require an equal number of disconnections before the network connection is terminated. This means that if the network connection is already connected when the Connect action is run, Disconnect will not terminate the connection (however, a further Disconnect action will terminate it.)"

This worked for me.

Regards